# where to put script that run in every / some activities in android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I want to put some script that needs to run in some activity like checking if my API token has changed or still remain same.

if in **Laravel**, we know about "middleware", one or more classes that can we run in some activities. is there any equivalent of middleware **Laravel** in android?

And is it safe to do authentication only on launcher activity? I mean in web development, we can't just put the script to do authentication only on the home page since people can't directly visit some pages by writing the URL without having visit home page.

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass all your activities from some base activity and do your checking in that base activity.

Authentication shall be done as soon as your current authentication token expires. So if you don't have authentication token then in any activity of yours. Again if all the activities are subclassed from same base one you can do that checking in the base activity.